# Reset steps counter Google fit?

Tags: java, android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I am trying to get all steps i am doing. But I want to be able to reset the steps counts when I want. Anybody knows?

Here is my code:

```
public class GoogleFitActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnDataPointListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final int REQUEST_OAUTH = 1;
    private static final String AUTH_PENDING = "auth_state_pending";
    private boolean authInProgress = false;
    private GoogleApiClient mApiClient;
    private GoogleFitDB mGoogleFitDB;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Fitness.SENSORS_API)
                .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE))
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

        DataSourcesRequest dataSourceRequest = new DataSourcesRequest.Builder()
                .setDataTypes( DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE )
                .setDataSourceTypes( DataSource.TYPE_RAW )
                .build();

        ResultCallback<DataSourcesResult> dataSourcesResultCallback = new ResultCallback<DataSourcesResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(DataSourcesResult dataSourcesResult) {
                for( DataSource dataSource : dataSourcesResult.getDataSources() ) {
                    if( DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE.equals( dataSource.getDataType() ) ) {
                        registerFitnessDataListener(dataSource, DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE);
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        Fitness.SensorsApi.findDataSources(mApiClient, dataSourceRequest)
                .setResultCallback(dataSourcesResultCallback);

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        if( !authInProgress ) {
            try {
                authInProgress = true;
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult( GoogleFitActivity.this, REQUEST_OAUTH );
            } catch(IntentSender.SendIntentException e ) {

            }
        } else {
            Log.e( "GoogleFit", "authInProgress" );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataPoint(DataPoint dataPoint) {

        for( final Field field : dataPoint.getDataType().getFields() ) {
            final Value value = dataPoint.getValue( field );
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mGoogleFitDB = new GoogleFitDB(field.getName(),value.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Field: " + field.getName() + " Value: " + value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mApiClient.connect();
    }

    private void registerFitnessDataListener(DataSource dataSource, DataType dataType) {

        SensorRequest request = new SensorRequest.Builder()
                .setDataSource( dataSource )
                .setDataType( dataType )
                .setSamplingRate( 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS )
                .build();


        Fitness.SensorsApi.add( mApiClient, request, this )
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
                        if (status.isSuccess()) {
                            Log.e( "GoogleFit", "SensorApi successfully added" );
                        }
                    }
                });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Fitness.SensorsApi.remove( mApiClient, this )
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
                        if (status.isSuccess()) {
                            mApiClient.disconnect();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBoolean(AUTH_PENDING, authInProgress);
    }


}
```

Comment: Reset in what sense? The cumulative step counter is just a count of the number of steps you've done since the source of the steps (e.g. the HW step counter) reset to zero. Can't you just pick a number of steps as your "zero", and subtract from the reported value?

Comment: I mean, set zero to the steps counter.

Comment: You can't. Just subtract your baseline value locally.

Comment: I have been looking for information. https://developers.google.com/fit/android/history#delete_data

Maybe if I delete the information, it would restart.

Comment: No, that will not reset it.